# Как получить логин telegram пользователя?

Tags: php, telegram, madelineproto

Имеется **id** пользователя. А как получить его Логин?

Пробовал так:

```
$UserFull = $MadelineProto->users->getFullUser(['id' => xxx]);
```

Но ничего не выходит.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Есть ошибки которые дает код? Или еще что?

Comment: Ошибку не даёт, логина не выдаёт.

Answer (score 0):

Метод `users->getFullUser` возращает `FullUser`.
`FullUser` имеет параметр `User`, который уже содержит `username`

Answer (score 0):

Как сказал @kotteni, в массиве user метода getFullUser будет логин (username). **Но его может и не быть.** Если вы не видите username, то у пользователя его просто нет.